# Different implementations of SHA1, which one is correct?

Tags: sha-1

I have noticed that different implementations of SHA1 give different results. As I'm currently programming my own SHA1 implementation (in MATLAB / GNU Octave), I wonder which one should I follow?

There are several implementations of SHA1 in [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/SHA-1). Using the message `Rosetta Code`, most of them give SHA1 hash of `48c98f7e5a6e736d790ab740dfc3f51a61abe2b5`.

There is also [Tools for Noobs Online sha1() function](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/), that gives the same hash as the examples in Rosetta Code.

In Rosetta Code, there are also two examples of computing SHA1 in Unix shell:

In my own computer (Debian Linux Wheezy amd64),`echo 'Rosetta Code' | sha1sum` gives a SHA1 hash of `d350d93ccda0fbf2d5037dedd2f3763fe880b2c5` and `echo 'Rosetta Code' | openssl sha1` also gives the same hash.

However, [the Rosetta Code examples of computing SHA1 in Unix Shell](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/SHA-1) use different message: `ASCII string` . According to Rosetta Code, `echo -n 'ASCII string' | sha1` should give `9e9aeefe5563845ec5c42c5630842048c0fc261b`, and `echo -n 'ASCII string' | openssl sha1 | sed 's/.*= //'` should give the same hash. When I try `ASCII string` as message in [Tools for Noobs Online sha1() function](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/), it gives the same hash as the examples of Rosetta Code on computing SHA1 in Unix shell. So I can conclude that all these implementations of SHA1 in Rosetta Code and also Tools for Noobs Online sha1() function give identical hashes.

In my own computer, using the message `ASCII string` I get the hash `4f9e000b925f5d96def1d9b3e21cdc11f1df6139` either by `echo 'ASCII string' | sha1sum` or `echo 'ASCII string' | openssl sha1`.

So, of all these implementations, only my own computer's `sha1sum` and `openssl sha1` differ from the examples of [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/SHA-1) and [Tools for Noobs Online sha1() function](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/sha1/). Has this something to do with the UTF-8 vs. ASCII, processor type, endianness, message suffixing differences or is there something wrong in my Linux configuration?

Comment: Sounds like something encoding related, but not UTF-8 vs. ASCII. Perhaps UTF-16?

Comment: Your problem is that you left out the -n option of echo. Therefore echo appends a newline character to your string before the string is passed to sha1sum or openssl.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `echo` command will include a newline at the end. So when you use `echo 'Rosetta Code' | sha1sum` you are actually hashing the string `Rosetta Code\n`.

Do the test using `echo -n`, the `-n` flag prevents the trailing newline character. Doing `echo -n 'Rosetta Code' | sha1sum` gives the same `48c98f7e5a6e736d790ab740dfc3f51a61abe2b5` hash that you were seeing elsewhere.

Comment: you are right!, but what should be done with the condition where the string already has new-line at the end of it example 'Rosetta Code\n' echo -n 'Rosetta Code\n' | sha1sum Seems like when we use 'echo -n' it removes all the trailing new-lines, including the one we have. I am asking it because, I am stuck with calculating sha1sum with above condition.

Comment: @MaheshPujari This is not a crypto question – maybe ask it on Unix Stack Exchange. (For me, `echo -n` doesn't seem to remove any newline, it just doesn't append a new one.)

Comment: @MaheshPujari Remember that echo doesn't interpret escapes, without the -e flag. So `echo -n 'Rosetta Code\n' is outputting the literal string 'Rosetta Code\n', with no new lines at all.

Answer (score 4):

SHA1 is fully described (including complete test vectors) in this [FIPS](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-2/fips180-2withchangenotice.pdf) publication, if you wanted to do it properly.  But I think checking against the final digests of a couple inputs should be enough to point you to the correct version. I extracted them for you (inputs in [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), quotation marks excluded):

"**abc**" (3 bytes)

```
A9993E364706816ABA3E25717850C26C9CD0D89D
```

"**abcdbcdecdefdefgefghfghighijhijkijkljklmklmnlmnomnopnopq**" (56 bytes)

```
84983E441C3BD26EBAAE4AA1F95129E5E54670F1
```

If you don't get those with any of your tools (endianness aside), well, to quote [NIST](http://www.nsrl.nist.gov/testdata/), you may have a problem.

If you are implementing SHA1, be sure to keep the .pdf I linked close to hand, it will be invaluable - it provides test vectors for every round and for many inputs, and can be used for SHA2 as well.